# How to place image icons in tab in android?

Tags: android, tabwidget

I need to implement the tab widget with icon in this screen shot.

[image]

Can anyone please explain how it needs to be implemented using fragments. If we click the image icon it should display listview.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far.

Comment: HI @sec_aw i followed this link http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/04/android-tabactivity-tab-layout-demo-tab.html .. but im not able to display image icon... Tabactivity  and getdrawable is depricated

Comment: Again, please post your code. Otherwise nobody can help you. You may edit your own question at any time.

Comment: post your adapter code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TabLayout` to do that.

xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:minHeight="100dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

code:

```
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(...));

      tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            switch (tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition()) {
                case 0:
                    //do what you want when tab 0 is selected
                    break;
                case 1:
                    //do what you want when tab 1 is selected
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //do what you want when tab 2 is selected
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```